# TestNG - Getting start time of before method

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm executing a few hundred tests in test classes consisting of a singular beforeMethod test, followed by a variable amount of primary tests and occasionally an afterMethod.

The purpose of the beforMethod test, is to populate the test environment with data used in the primary tests while separating logging and recording from the primary tests, which we report on.

We have set up an automatic issue creation tool using a listener. We've found that it would give great value to add execution time to this tool, so that it can show us how long it would take to reproduce the errors in said issues.

To this end, I have made a simple addition to this code, that uses ITestResult.getEndMillis() and getStartMillis() to get the execution time.
The problem we're experiencing with this approach, is that if the test encounters a failure during the primary tests, ITestResult.getStartMillis() will not account for the start time of the before method, but only the primary method.

How would we go about determining the start time of the test class itself (always the beforeMethod), rather than just the current method?

Since we're running hundreds of tests in a massive setup, a solution that allows this without changing each separate test class, would definitely be preferable.

The setup of the java test classes look something like this (scrubbed of business specifics):

```
package foobar;

import foobar

@UsingTunnel
@Test
public class FLOWNAME_TESTNAME extends TestBase {

    private final Value<String> parameter;

    public FLOWNAME_TESTNAME(Value<String> parameter) {
        super(PropertyProviderImpl.get());
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    @StoryCreating(test = "TESTNAME")
    @BeforeMethod
    public void CONDITIONS() throws Throwable {
        new TESTNAME_CONDITIONS(parameter).executeTest();
    }

    @TestCoverage(test = "TESTNAME")
    public void PRIMARYTESTS() throws Throwable {
        TESTCASE1 testcase1 = new TESTCASE1(parameter.get());
        testcase1.executeTest();
        testcase1.throwSoftAsserts();

        TESTCASE2 testcase2 = new TESTCASE2(parameter.get());
        testcase2.executeTest();
        testcase2.throwSoftAsserts();
    }
}
```

So in this case, the problem arises when the listener detects a failure in either TESTCASE1 or TESTCASE2, because these will not include the execution time of TESTNAME_CONDITIONS because that test is inside a different method, yet practically speaking, they are part of the same test flow, aka the same test class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the issue.
It is possible to use ITestResult.getTestContext().getStartDate().getTime() to obtain the time of which the test class itself is run, rather than the current test method.

The final solution was quite simply:

> result.getEndMillis() - result.getTestContext().getStartDate().getTime()) / 60000

Where "result" corresponds to ITestResult.

This outputs the time between the start of the test and the end of the last executed method.